# How to pipe multiple inputs into a python script via the shell?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking to input a few strings into a python script so I can do test on my computer not http://www.ideone.com. But the ways I'm doing it all combine the strings instead of making them into lines or separate lines.

My code for python is 0001.py

```
testCases = int(input())
Counter = 0
while Counter < testCases:

    Line = str(input())
    countTwo = 1
    for i in range(int(len(Line)/2)):
        if countTwo % 2 == 0:
            print(Line[i], end='')
        countTwo += 1
    print('\n', end='')

    Counter += 1
```

I'm trying to do something like echo '5' 'hello' 'hello' 'hello' 'hello' | python3 001.py

Comment: What OS is your computer?  Not all echo commands are the same.

Comment: The strings must be separated by newlines.

Comment: I'm using Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
echo -e "line1\nline2\nline3"
```

This works because programs take input line by line. This echo statement separates the inputs over lines so it functions like you want.

Answer (score 2):

Editing now that you've provided your OS.

For Linux, this works (credit to @pteronewone who also answered):

```
$ echo -e "5\nhello\nhello\nhello\nhello\nhello" | python3 001.py
e
e
e
e
e
```

For Windows (leaving here for future reference), this is ugly and inefficient but works (Windows 7 cmd.exe shell):

```
C:\> (echo 5 & echo hello & echo hello & echo hello & echo hello & echo hello) | 001.py
e
e
e
e
e
```

(Not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but that's what your script outputs.)

A few other suggestions:

Wrap the input() in a try/except.  In your example you only included four "hello" but told it to expect five, so it tries to read a fifth input which results in an exception.

```
try:
    Line = str(input())
except:
    break
```

Use the integer division operator `//` so you don't need to cast from `float` back to `int` in your `range()`.

```
for i in range(len(Line) // 2):
```